# Upgrading Cassandra 3.11.8 to 4.1.0 returns "AssertionError: null" on startup while loading the schema

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to upgrade my 3 node Cassandra cluster from version 3.11.8 to 4.1.0.
The steps I have taken are:-

- Do a nodetool drain on the old 3.11.8 version
- Stop the old version
- Download and put in place the new 4.1.0 version
- Amend config files to reflect new 4.1.0 version
- Start new cassandra version

However, I am seeing the following error message in the debug.log/system.log and Cassandra won't start successfully:

```
ERROR [main] 2023-03-08 10:16:13,168 CassandraDaemon.java:898 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.TableMetadata$CompactTableMetadata.getCompactValueColumn(TableMetadata.java:1593)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.TableMetadata$CompactTableMetadata.<init>(TableMetadata.java:1428)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.TableMetadata$Builder.build(TableMetadata.java:753)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:951)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:906)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:865)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:856)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:844)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.DefaultSchemaUpdateHandler.reload(DefaultSchemaUpdateHandler.java:275)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.DefaultSchemaUpdateHandler.reset(DefaultSchemaUpdateHandler.java:287)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:143)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:282)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:752)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:876)
```

Does anybody have any ideas what this means or how I should go about debugging this?

For info, I get the same error if I try and upgrade to 4.0.7

I CAN get my database to upgrade to 3.11.14, so the error seems to be related to upgrading to a version 4.X database.

Does anybody have any ideas what the above errors mean?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the replies.
The issue was indeed related to my usage of COMPACT STORAGE.
As soon as I removed that, all was good.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of [C* 3.x is `3.11.14`](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) and I'd recommend you first try to upgrade from `3.11.8` -> `3.11.14` prior to making it to `4.1.0`. I'm not positive if you need to be on some form of `4.0.latest` prior to hitting `4.1.latest`. [Here](https://www.datastax.com/learn/whats-new-for-cassandra-4/migrating-cassandra-4x) is a hands-on lab where you could try practicing the upgrade from 3.x to 4.x to get comfortable and understand the steps involved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Today I have actually tried upgrading to 3.11.14 and that worked, but when I tried to upgrade to 4.1.0 (from 3.11.14) it failed with the same error. I also tried upgrading to 4.0.7 and that failed with the same error, so there appears to be something on my database that isn't compliant with version 4.0.X or 4.1.0. Do you have any ideas how to check what the incompatability might be please?

Comment: It is very hard to triage this type of problem in a forum space and I'd recommend you to reach out [here](https://join.slack.com/t/the-asf/shared_invite/zt-1qrh7hjfb-fmNTUXYaPkM2fONKop2RwQ) (the invite expires in 30 days) to post entire log files and discuss with the experts out there in the [#cassandra channel](https://the-asf.slack.com/archives/CJZLTM05A).

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace indicates that Cassandra fails to start because it ran into a situation when loading the schema. It appears one of the tables has a `null` column in the schema for whatever reason.

Based on the stack trace, it appears to be a Thrift table (`COMPACT STORAGE`) that has the problem.

It may or may not be related but you've missed a lot of steps as part of the upgrade. When performing an upgrade, you need to follow every single upgrade step documented in [`NEWS.txt`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/NEWS.txt).

For example, you need to follow ALL the upgrade steps:

- from C* 3.11.8 to C* 3.11.latest;
- from C* 4.0 to 4.0.latest
- from C* 4.1

Note that Cassandra 4.1 can read SSTable formats all the way back to [version `ma` in C* 3.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L125) (C* 3.11.8 uses [SSTable format version `md`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.8/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L113)) so it is possible to upgrade directly from C* 3.11 to C* 4.1.

After you have completed all the steps in `NEWS.txt`, try upgrading your cluster again. Cheers!